# getting compiler error in intelliJ IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classpath

Actually I updated my jdk today but when I opened intelliJ I wasn't able to compile any class..It showed the following message..
"java: System Java Compiler was not found in classpath"
Please help me out.

Answer (score 5):

The "Project SDK" is probably missing.

Check under `File > Project Structure > Project`

If it says `<No SDK>`, click `New...` and navigate to your new JDK home directory.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the Java SDK you are setting in IntelliJ IDE is the same you have settled as your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

IntelliJ is probably matching the path you settled in the IDE with what you have in JAVA_HOME, which might lead to this problem.